# Version 1.35: Fatal exception of type MWException Error, The code that appears is:

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

Anyone know what I'm supposed to do?

[cb49891230242084931e4968] /index.php?title=%D7%99%D7%97%D7%99%D7%93%D7%94:%D7%AA%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%A2&action=submit MWException from line 95 of /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaStandalone/LuaStandaloneInterpreter.php: The lua binary (/home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaStandalone/binaries/lua5_1_5_linux_64_generic/lua) is not executable.

Backtrace:

#0 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaStandalone/LuaStandaloneEngine.php(104): Scribunto_LuaStandaloneInterpreter->__construct(Scribunto_LuaStandaloneEngine, array)
#1 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaCommon/LuaEngine.php(120): Scribunto_LuaStandaloneEngine->newInterpreter()
#2 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaStandalone/LuaStandaloneEngine.php(16): Scribunto_LuaEngine->load()
#3 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaCommon/LuaEngine.php(223): Scribunto_LuaStandaloneEngine->load()
#4 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaCommon/LuaModule.php(38): Scribunto_LuaEngine->getInterpreter()
#5 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaCommon/LuaModule.php(25): Scribunto_LuaModule->getInitChunk()
#6 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/common/ScribuntoEngineBase.php(193): Scribunto_LuaModule->validate()
#7 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/common/ScribuntoContent.php(35): ScribuntoEngineBase->validate(string, string)
#8 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/common/Hooks.php(366): ScribuntoContent->validate(Title)
#9 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/includes/HookContainer/HookContainer.php(320): ScribuntoHooks::validateScript(DerivativeContext, ScribuntoContent, Status, string, User, boolean)
#10 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/includes/HookContainer/HookContainer.php(131): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookContainer->callLegacyHook(string, array, array, array)
#11 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/includes/HookContainer/HookRunner.php(1529): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookContainer->run(string, array)
#12 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/includes/EditPage.php(1903): MediaWiki\HookContainer\HookRunner->onEditFilterMergedContent(DerivativeContext, ScribuntoContent, Status, string, User, boolean)
#13 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/includes/EditPage.php(2231): EditPage->runPostMergeFilters(ScribuntoContent, Status, User)
#14 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/includes/EditPage.php(1723): EditPage->internalAttemptSave(NULL, boolean)
#15 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/includes/EditPage.php(680): EditPage->attemptSave(NULL)
#16 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/includes/actions/EditAction.php(71): EditPage->edit()
#17 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/includes/actions/SubmitAction.php(38): EditAction->show()
#18 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/includes/MediaWiki.php(527): SubmitAction->show()
#19 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/includes/MediaWiki.php(313): MediaWiki->performAction(Article, Title)
#20 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/includes/MediaWiki.php(940): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#21 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/includes/MediaWiki.php(543): MediaWiki->main()
#22 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/index.php(53): MediaWiki->run()
#23 /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/index.php(46): wfIndexMain()
#24 {main}

תפריט ניווט

Comment: Use code blocks in your question (search for Markdown inline code blocks). And use English only.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the Lua file executable: `sudo chmod +x /home/u657493073/domains/tzefunotwiki.com/public_html/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaStandalone/binaries/lua5_1_5_linux_64_generic/lua`.